# Turn speaker to ON on call connect

Tags: android

I'm trying to dial a number and when the call connects turn ON the speaker.
I've already read lots of topics that achieve this problem, but cannot get it working.
This is what I have.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Context context = (Context)getApplicationContext();
AudioManager audioManager2 = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
audioManager2.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager2.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

The listener is working fine. I can see the toast "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK" when the call is established, but the rest of the code is not working.

Am I missing something ? 
Thanks !

UPDATE

This are my permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

UPDATE 2

Actually calling:

```
audioManager2.isSpeakerphoneOn()
```

returns **false** before

```
audioManager2.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

and

```
audioManager2.isSpeakerphoneOn()
```

returns **true** after

```
audioManager2.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

but the speaker really did not turn **ON**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the option "AUDIO_SETTINGS" on true in your manifest?

Comment: Yes i did...<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>